# Use en-US instead of en_us locale code

Tags: localization

I want to use locales like `en-US` instead of `en_us`.
Is there a way to do this other than creating totally new locales?
Can I set it up at the siteUrl ?

Comment: Could you elaborate on your use case?

Comment: I mean than instead of using the en_us code in the Url to get the en_us content i would like to use en-US , like http://www.example.com/en-US/homepage, is that possible?

Comment: Ok, have you read [the official docs on the subject](https://craftcms.com/docs/localization-guide#step-4-define-your-site-uRLs)?

Answer (score 2):

When [defining](https://craftcms.com/docs/localization-guide#step-4-define-your-site-uRLs) your [siteUrl](https://craftcms.com/docs/config-settings#siteUrl), you can do:

```
return array(
    // ...
    'siteUrl' => array(
        'en_us' => 'http://example.com/en-US/',
        // ...
    ),
);
```

Comment: Yeah this is what i tried to do.So the Url seems to be accepted, i mean i dont get a 404 but i dont get any content either, just getting an empty page.And also after doing the change at the siteUrl if i hit the Url with en_us i still get the content.Do i need to do any other change on the CMS or something ?

Comment: Sounds like something else is wrong in your localization setup.  I'd recommend going through the guide step-by-step: https://craftcms.com/docs/localization-guide